# How to configure sql developer for r12.1.1 vision instance on windows server 2008

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, windows-server-2008-r2, erp

I have successfully installed r12.1.1 vision instance erp in my laptop. And its working.

I now want to query back end tables using SQL developer. Both SQL developer and SQL plus are installed with media pack itself.

I now want to configure vision instance into SQL developer.

Where can I get the hostname, port and sid details.

Also when I opened SQL plus and gave apps\apps it gave me the following error message.

> ORA-12650: TNS:PROTOCOL ADAPTER ERROR

kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Got it myself figured it out...

Hostname - is the name which we use to connect to frontend application page(which is also the full name of the computer)

Port - by default it is 1521

Instead of SID use service name - by default it is 'VIS'

And all these can be found under the tnsnames.Ora file.

Thanks to Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
USER:APPS
PASSWORD:APPS
HOST:(I USED SERVER IP EXAMPLE: 192.168.100.140)
PORT:1521
SID:VISION
```